# Slick 3.1.1 Stream -- Pagination

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to use Slick Stream to achieve the behavior of **pagination**.
My Dao code looks like:

```
def getStreamCompanies: DatabasePublisher[CompanyVO] = {
    val disableAutoCommit = SimpleDBIO(_.connection.setAutoCommit(false))
    val action = companies.take(50).result.withStatementParameters(fetchSize = 10)
    dbConfig.db.stream(disableAutoCommit andThen action)
}
```

My Controller code looks like:

```
def getStreamCompanies = Action {
    implicit val companyWrites: Writes[CompanyVO] = Json.writes[CompanyVO]
    val publisher = CompanyService.getStreamCompanies
    val enumerator = Streams.publisherToEnumerator(publisher)
    Ok.chunked(enumerator map companyWrites.writes)
}
```

With the current approach, I am getting 10 companies as response. But when I request again, I get this error

```
slick.SlickException: Read NULL value for ResultSet column <computed>
at slick.jdbc.BaseResultConverter$mcD$sp.read$mcD$sp(JdbcResultConverter.scala:13) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.jdbc.BaseResultConverter$mcD$sp.read(JdbcResultConverter.scala:11) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.jdbc.BaseResultConverter$mcD$sp.read(JdbcResultConverter.scala:10) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.relational.ProductResultConverter.read(ResultConverter.scala:56) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.relational.ProductResultConverter.read(ResultConverter.scala:46) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.relational.TypeMappingResultConverter.read(ResultConverter.scala:136) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.driver.JdbcInvokerComponent$QueryInvokerImpl.extractValue(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:37) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker$$anon$1.extractValue(StatementInvoker.scala:67) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.fetchNext(PositionedResult.scala:176) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator$class.slick$util$ReadAheadIterator$$update(ReadAheadIterator.scala:34) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator$class.hasNext(ReadAheadIterator.scala:40) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.hasNext(PositionedResult.scala:167) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$class.emitStream(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:31) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl$$anon$1.emitStream(JdbcActionComponent.scala:218) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl$$anon$1.emitStream(JdbcActionComponent.scala:218) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:285) ~[slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
```

How to proceed further?
What is the purpose of **chunked**?

Comment: Sorry, chunked is not a pagination solution https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream#Chunked-responses

Comment: So, How do I achieve pagination?

Comment: Simplest way in slick to do pagination is, send a page parameter to your action and use drop and take to get the results you want. http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering . You might want to look into websockets if normal request-response is not what you need.